# Finding the elements in a range in awk

Tags: awk

I have two files that have integers in one file and ranges in another. The one having integers :

```
integer.txt -->

A 68 V K 99187
A 98 J K 99107
A 78 V K 99188
1 89 V C 88373
2 99 C F 88999
3 100 C H 88744
X 101 E J 88779

ranges.txt --> 

A 28 78 YELLOW
1 33 89 BLUE
2 46 111 PURPLE
X 77 199 BLACK
X 101 299 GREEN
X 102 397 RED
```

What I am trying to have is, if the `first column` of `integer.txt` and `range.txt` is the same, getting the integers which fit in between the `column 2nd` and `3rd` ( `range` ) of `ranges.txt., even it is in the border overlap ( = smaller and equal to and larger and equal to ).

What I have tried is:

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {intt[$1]=$2; max[$1]=$3; next}
    {
        for (color in intt) 
            if (intt[color] < $2 && intt[color] == $2 && $2 < max[color] && $2 == max[color] ) {
                print $0, color
                break
            }
    }
'
```

What I expect is :

```
A 28 78   YELLOW  A 68 V K 99187
A 28 78   YELLOW  A 78 V K 99188
1 33 89   BLUE    1 89 V C 88373 
2 46 111  PURPLE  2 99 C F 88999
X 77 199  BLACK   X 101 E J 88779
X 101 299 GREEN   X 101 E J 88779
```

In the expected output, I dont expect to see `X 102 397 RED` as any of the lines beginning with `X` do not fall in between `102 and 397`..

I am aware that my code is in horrible condition now, but how do I fix it?

Comment: Yes. I have added now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk for multi-dimelnsional arrays:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ key = $1 }
NR==FNR {
    color = $4
    beg[key][color] = $2
    end[key][color] = $3
    all[key][color] = $0
    next
}
key in all {
    for (color in all[key]) {
        if ( ($2 >= beg[key][color]) && ($2 <= end[key][color]) ) {
            print all[key][color], $0
        }
    }
}

$ gawk -f tst.awk ranges.txt integer.txt
A 28 78 YELLOW A 68 V K 99187
A 28 78 YELLOW A 78 V K 99188
1 33 89 BLUE 1 89 V C 88373
2 46 111 PURPLE 2 99 C F 88999
X 101 299 GREEN X 101 E J 88779
X 77 199 BLACK X 101 E J 88779
```

Comment: It basically just fixes the syntax of what you were already trying to do with your code. Do you have any specific questions about any part of it?

Comment: It works very well, thank you. Well, I think the problem was coming from me not being able to set the ˝[][]˝. What did you grab by doing this?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. arr[] is an array, arr[][] is an array of arrays. arr["foo"]=7 saves the scalar 7 in arr["foo"] and arr["foo"]["bar"]=7 saves the scalar 7 in arr["foo"]["bar"].

Comment: I see. Thank you!